# Plotting Points on a map in R Help needed

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am pretty new to R and want to learn how to plot points on R. I have managed to create a map of the UK with the following code

the Trust/longlat.csv data is a list of organisations with Longitude and Lattitude co-ordinates.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

worldmap = map_data('world')

knitr::kable(head(worldmap, 20))



ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
                    aes(x = long, 
                        y = lat, 
                        group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-10,3), 
          ylim = c(50.3, 59))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
           aes(x = long, 
               y = lat, 
               group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
          xlim = c(-10,3), 
          ylim = c(50, 59))

library(tidyverse)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, 
               group = group), 
           fill = 'gray90', 
           color = 'black') + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
          xlim = c(-10,3), 
          ylim = c(50, 59))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, 
               group = group), 
           fill = 'gray90', 
           color = 'black') + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
          xlim = c(-10,3), 
          ylim = c(50, 59)) + 
  theme_void()

Data<-read.csv("C:/Users/Digital/Desktop/longlat.csv")
```

Comment: You could add points by adding a `geom_point` layer. Something like `+ geom_point(data = Data, aes(x = long, y = lat))`

Comment: Thank you excuse my ignorance but where would the + be added?   Would it be like so ? ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, 
               group = group), 
           fill = 'gray90', 
           color = 'black') + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
          xlim = c(-10,3), 
          ylim = c(50, 59)) + 
  theme_void()+ geom_point(data = Data, aes(x = long, y = lat))   ??

Comment: Yep. That should do, even if personally I would add straight after geom_polygon just  to have all geoms in one place.

Comment: Like so ?   It's not working also the theme_void() is being ignored and the map is still filled in
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, 
                   group = group), 
               fill = 'gray90', 
               color = 'black') + 
  geom_point(Data = Data, aes(x = long, y = lat)+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
              xlim = c(-10,3), 
              ylim = c(50, 59)) + 
  theme_void()